# Sandwiching one country between countries on a Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen-visas

I got my Schengen visa from the German Embassy. I don't enter the Schengen area in Germany, but that's where my longest stay is (4 days)  which is why I applied through Germany.

However, I plan to sandwich Prague (2 days) between Munich (2 days) and Berlin (2 days). This is a slight change from my itinerary which I had provided during my visa application. Is that allowed or would the border officials have a problem with that?

Comment: Are you just extending your trip, or leaving some other destination out? How long is your trip in total (2 days is a more major change in a 6 day trip than in a 20 day trip)?

Comment: Its a 14 day trip in total. Not extending my trip. Not leaving out  or adding any country. Changing Berlin from 4 days to 2 days and spending those 2 days in Munich. Just that I wont be in GER for 4 continuous days but it'll be sandwiched with Prague in between

Answer (score 1):

- You are allowed to make minor changes to your itinerary after you get the visa.
- You are not allowed to misrepresent your itinerary to get your visa, and you should avoid giving the impression that you lied.

Since both the old and the new itinerary would have Germany as the main destination, it sounds unlikely that there would be the *suspicion* that you lied to get the visa.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have one question: I contacted the vfs germany office (they handle the visa applications). They recommended that I should email the German embassy and confirm the itinerary change with them. I'm refraining from doing it because the embassy might not be willing to confirm things on email and might just reject my change just to be on the safer side. I'm planning on not emailing them. What do you reckon?

Comment: @qwerty_uiop, you already contacted VFS, so it is a little late to keep it quiet. You have their professional advice, so follow it.